# call More than suspend in coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

1-have list of object => objects

2 - call abi number for all object in list

3- calculate all result from API's in one list

Example ->

```
list1 = (obj1,obj2,obj3)

var total =mutableList<String>()

  coroutineScope{
 
      list1.foreach{obj->
           val result = repository.contactEndPoint(obj)    
          total.add(result.await())
    }
  }

   emit(total)  // this is in flow
```

problem is return firs object call .

how can don't return before finishing all call's???

Answer (score 0):

Use `map`, `async`, and `awaitAll`. This will also run them in parallel.

```
val total = coroutineScope {
    list1.map { obj ->
        async { repository.contactEndPoint(obj).await() }
    }.awaitAll()
}
emit(total)
```

Comment: val total = coroutineScope {
                contactList.map { obj ->
                    async { findFriendsContactsRepository.findFriendsContacts(obj) }
                }.awaitAll()

            }




run app 1 => Call first one obj in list
run app 2 => Call all obj in list